# Convert a 0-1 value to a hex colour?

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, rgb, rgba

I'm creating an app that visualises stars using a NASA API. The colour of a star comes back as a 0 to 1 value, with 0 being pure blue, and 1 being pure red. Essentially I need to set up a way to convert 0-1 values in javascript to a sliding HEX (or rgb) scale, progressing like this:

```
0: blue (9aafff)
.165: blue white (cad8ff)
.33: white (f7f7ff)
.495: yellow white (fcffd4)
.66: yellow (fff3a1)
.825: orange (ffa350)
1: red (fb6252)
```

Is this possible? I don't have any idea how to even begin to approach this. Cheers!

Comment: SURE it is possible. But what are is the relation between the value [0 1] and the colors? Is it an interpolation between 0 & 0.165 => Blue, blue,white ?

Comment: @AlexisPaques, Yes it is an interpolation. Like I said, sliding scale. Values could land anywhere between 0 and 1 (although I think they're rounded off at some point, and if I makes it easier I could use js to round them off whenever).

Comment: Can you add send the equivalent RGB value of "blue white", "yellow white", "yellow", "orange" ? For blue white, is it #7777FF ?

Comment: @AlexisPaques, Sure, I've added specific hex codes to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best would be to work in another color space than the RGB one. For example [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

Example:

```
var stones = [ // Your Data
  {v:0, hex:'#9aafff'},
  {v:.165, hex:'#cad8ff'},
  {v:.33, hex:'#f7f7ff'},
  {v:.495, hex:'#fcffd4'},
  {v:.66, hex:'#fff3a1'},
  {v:.825, hex:'#ffa350'},
  {v:1, hex:'#fb6252'},
]
stones.forEach(function(s){
  s.rgb = hexToRgb(s.hex);
  s.hsl = rgbToHsl.apply(0, s.rgb);
});

function valueToRgbColor(val){
  for (var i=1; i<stones.length; i++) {
    if (val<=stones[i].v) {
      var k = (val-stones[i-1].v)/(stones[i].v-stones[i-1].v),
          hsl = interpolArrays(stones[i-1].hsl, stones[i].hsl, k);
      return 'rgb('+hslToRgb.apply(0,hsl).map(function(v){ return v|0})+')';
    }
  }
  throw "bad value";
}
```

```js
/**
 * Converts an RGB color value to HSL. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes r, g, and b are contained in the set [0, 255] and
 * returns h, s, and l in the set [0, 1].
 *
 * @param   Number  r       The red color value
 * @param   Number  g       The green color value
 * @param   Number  b       The blue color value
 * @return  Array           The HSL representation
 */
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b){
    r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
    var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
    var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

    if(max == min){
        h = s = 0; // achromatic
    }else{
        var d = max - min;
        s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
        switch(max){
            case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
            case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
            case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
        }
        h /= 6;
    }

    return [h, s, l];
}

/**
 * Converts an HSL color value to RGB. Conversion formula
 * adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space.
 * Assumes h, s, and l are contained in the set [0, 1] and
 * returns r, g, and b in the set [0, 255].
 *
 * @param   Number  h       The hue
 * @param   Number  s       The saturation
 * @param   Number  l       The lightness
 * @return  Array           The RGB representation
 */
function hslToRgb(h, s, l){
    var r, g, b;

    if(s == 0){
        r = g = b = l; // achromatic
    }else{
        function hue2rgb(p, q, t){
            if(t < 0) t += 1;
            if(t > 1) t -= 1;
            if(t < 1/6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
            if(t < 1/2) return q;
            if(t < 2/3) return p + (q - p) * (2/3 - t) * 6;
            return p;
        }

        var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
        var p = 2 * l - q;
        r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1/3);
        g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
        b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1/3);
    }

    return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}


function hexToRgb(hex) {
    return /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex)
    .slice(1).map(function(v){ return parseInt(v,16) });
}

function interpolArrays(a,b,k){
  var c = a.slice();
  for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) c[i]+=(b[i]-a[i])*k;
  return c;
}

var stones = [ // Your Data
  {v:0, hex:'#9aafff'},
  {v:.165, hex:'#cad8ff'},
  {v:.33, hex:'#f7f7ff'},
  {v:.495, hex:'#fcffd4'},
  {v:.66, hex:'#fff3a1'},
  {v:.825, hex:'#ffa350'},
  {v:1, hex:'#fb6252'},
]
stones.forEach(function(s){
  s.rgb = hexToRgb(s.hex);
  s.hsl = rgbToHsl.apply(0, s.rgb);
});

function valueToRgbColor(val){
  for (var i=1; i<stones.length; i++) {
    if (val<=stones[i].v) {
      var k = (val-stones[i-1].v)/(stones[i].v-stones[i-1].v),
          hsl = interpolArrays(stones[i-1].hsl, stones[i].hsl, k);
      return 'rgb('+hslToRgb.apply(0,hsl).map(function(v){ return v|0})+')';
    }
  }
  throw "bad value";
}

for (var i=0; i<=1; i+=.03) {
  var color = valueToRgbColor(i);
  $('<div>').css({background:color}).text(i.toFixed(2)+" -> "+color).appendTo('body');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}
div {
  width:200px;
  margin:auto;
  color: #333;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For this example, I took the color space conversion functions [here](http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c) but there are easy to find once you know what to look for.

Note that modern browsers understand HSL colors (exemple: `background: hsl(120,100%, 50%);`) so, if you're just building HTML, you don't have to embed all this code in your page, just precompute the color stops and interpolate on the HSL values directly.

Comment: This shows the general theory of color interpolation, but not the (somewhat significant) aspect of pulling from a list of gradient stops. Is that intentional?

Comment: @ssube The idea was that our purpose isn't to do OP's work but to guide. But I then realized it wasn't so easy, so I edited with a way to follow a path of colours.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I wasn't aware browsers understood HSL. Sorry I am very new to js, can you explain how I'd modify your code to just produce HSL? Fetch those hex colours in HSL values and then interpolate?

Comment: @JohnDoe Exactly. Start by computing the HSL values offline (or grab them in my code snippet) then do the interpolation directly on their parts. The reason to prefer that instead of the whole code I showed is that you have less code to send to the browsers.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Yes, I understand the concept, I'm just not sure how to go about the interpolation. Do you know of any good tuts or examples?

Comment: I've shown the interpolation part in my answer, it works on hsl colors already (the first step, in the stones.forEach loop being the conversion to HSL. You should try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one the solution in pure Javascript I just did. It process a linear interpolation between two colors.

```
/* 
NASA color to RGB function
by Alexis Paques

It process a linear interpolation between two colors, here is the scheme:
0: blue
.165: blue white
.33: white
.495: yellow white
.66: yellow
.825: orange
1: red
*/

var blue = [0,0,255];
var bluewhite = [127,127,255];
var white = [255,255,255];
var yellowwhite = [255,255,127];
var yellow = [255,255,0];
var orange = [255,127,0];
var red = [255,0,0];
function color01toRGB(color01){
  var RGB = [0,0,0];
  var fromRGB = [0,0,0];
  var toRGB = [0,0,0];
  if(!color01)
    return '#000000';
  if(color01 > 1 || color01 < 0)
    return '#000000';
  if(color01 >= 0 && color01 <= 0.165 ){
    fromRGB = blue;
    toRGB = bluewhite;
  }
  else if(color01 > 0.165 && color01 <= 0.33 ){
    fromRGB = bluewhite;
    toRGB = white;
  }
  else if(color01 > 0.33 && color01 <= 0.495 ){
    fromRGB = white;
    toRGB = yellowwhite;
  }
  else if(color01 > 0.495 && color01 <= 0.66 ){
    fromRGB = yellowwhite;
    toRGB = yellow;
  }
  else if(color01 > 0.66 && color01 <= 0.825 ){
    fromRGB = yellow;
    toRGB = orange;
  }
  else if(color01 > 0.825 && color01 <= 1 ){
    fromRGB = orange;
    toRGB = red;
  }

  // 0.165
  for (var i = RGB.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    RGB[i] = Math.round(fromRGB[i]*color01/0.165 + toRGB[i]*(1-color01/0.165)).toString(16);
  };

  return '#' + RGB.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of values, all pretty well-saturated and bright, you can probably interpolate in the current (RGB) space for this. It won't be quite as pretty as if you convert to HSL, but will work fine for the colors you have.

Since you don't have any weighting or curves in the data, going with a simple linear interpolation should work just fine. Something like:

```js
var stops = [
  [0, 154, 175, 255],
  [0.165, 202, 216, 255],
  [0.33, 247, 247, 255],
  [0.495, 252, 255, 212],
  [0.66, 255, 243, 161],
  [0.825, 255, 163, 80],
  [1, 251, 98, 82]
];

function convertColor(color) {
  var c = Math.min(Math.max(color, 0), 1); // Clamp between 0 and 1

  // Find the first stop below c
  var startIndex = 0;
  for (; stops[startIndex][0] < c && startIndex < stops.length; ++startIndex) {
    // nop
  }
  var start = stops[startIndex];
  console.log('using stop', startIndex, 'as start');

  // Find the next stop (above c)
  var stopIndex = startIndex + 1;
  if (stopIndex >= stops.length) {
    stopIndex = stops.length - 1;
  }
  var stop = stops[stopIndex];
  console.log('using stop', stopIndex, 'as stop');

  // Find the distance from start to c and start to stop
  var range = stop[0] - start[0];
  var diff = c - start[0];

  // Convert diff into a ratio from start to stop
  if (range > 0) {
    diff /= range;
  }

  console.log('interpolating', c, 'between', stop[0], 'and', start[0], 'by', diff);

  // Convert from RGB to HSL
  var a = rgbToHsl(start[1], start[2], start[3]);
  var b = rgbToHsl(stop[1], stop[2], stop[3]);
  console.log('hsl stops', a, b);

  // Interpolate between the two colors (start * diff + (stop * (1 - diff)))
  var out = [0, 0, 0];
  out[0] = a[0] * diff + (b[0] * (1 - diff));
  out[1] = a[1] * diff + (b[1] * (1 - diff));
  out[2] = a[2] * diff + (b[2] * (1 - diff));
  console.log('interpolated', out);

  // Convert back from HSL to RGB  
  var r = hslToRgb(out[0], out[1], out[2]);
  r = r.map(function(rv) {
    // Round each component of the output
    return Math.round(rv);
  });

  return r;
}

// Set the divs
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.star');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(star) {
  var color = convertColor(star.dataset.color);
  var colorStr = 'rgb(' + color[0] + ',' + color[1] + ',' + color[2] + ')';
  console.log('setting', star, 'to', colorStr);
  star.style.backgroundColor = colorStr;
});

// HSL to RGB conversion from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30758827/129032
function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
  r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
  var max = Math.max(r, g, b),
    min = Math.min(r, g, b);
  var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

  if (max == min) {
    h = s = 0; // achromatic
  } else {
    var d = max - min;
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
    switch (max) {
      case r:
        h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0);
        break;
      case g:
        h = (b - r) / d + 2;
        break;
      case b:
        h = (r - g) / d + 4;
        break;
    }
    h /= 6;
  }

  return [h, s, l];
}

function hslToRgb(h, s, l) {
  var r, g, b;

  if (s == 0) {
    r = g = b = l; // achromatic
  } else {
    function hue2rgb(p, q, t) {
      if (t < 0) t += 1;
      if (t > 1) t -= 1;
      if (t < 1 / 6) return p + (q - p) * 6 * t;
      if (t < 1 / 2) return q;
      if (t < 2 / 3) return p + (q - p) * (2 / 3 - t) * 6;
      return p;
    }

    var q = l < 0.5 ? l * (1 + s) : l + s - l * s;
    var p = 2 * l - q;
    r = hue2rgb(p, q, h + 1 / 3);
    g = hue2rgb(p, q, h);
    b = hue2rgb(p, q, h - 1 / 3);
  }

  return [r * 255, g * 255, b * 255];
}
```

```css
.star {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 16px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.66);
}
```

```html
<div class="star" data-color="0.0"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.05"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.1"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.15"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.2"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.25"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.3"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.35"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.4"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.45"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.5"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.55"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.6"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.65"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.7"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.75"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.8"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.85"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.9"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="0.95"></div>
<div class="star" data-color="1.0"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is incredibly helpful. However it doesn't seem to produce the intended spectrum(?). [Here is the spectrum I'm trying to reproduce](https://imgur.com/BoPbAU0).

Comment: I suspect that's an artifact of working in RGB. Looks like it doesn't work quite as well as I thought. @DenysSéguret 's answer has the RGB <-> HSL conversion that would sort that out, and I'll edit something similar into my answer in a sec.

Comment: @ssube I have a complete answers with stop definition ;)